# Calculate sum from different array columns

Tags: php, arrays

right at the start: I'm kind of new to PHP and arrays in particular but trying to learn as good as I can. I'm thankful for every help I can get.

Right now I'm desperatley trying to calculate sums from an multi-dimensional array which looks like follows:

```
Date -> Medium -> Device -> KPI
```

In an example:

```
2014-09-10 :: organic :: desktop :: visits == 10<br>
2014-09-10 :: organic :: tablet :: visits == 3<br>
2014-09-10 :: organic :: desktop :: conversion = 1.9<br>
2014-09-10 :: organic :: tablet :: conversion = 1.2<br>
2014-09-10 :: paid :: desktop :: visits == 9<br>
2014-09-10 :: paid :: tablet :: visits == 4<br>
2014-09-10 :: paid :: desktop :: conversion = 3.4<br>
2014-09-10 :: paid :: tablet :: conversion = 3.1
```

**Question 1:** How can I calculate the sums of all visits or all conversion rates?

**Question 2:** How can I calculate of e.g. all conversion rates on tablets?

I tried using array_sum but can't figure out how to break it down on different parameters. I was thinking about something like `array_sum($thearray['2014-09-10']['visits']` but this might have been to easy thinking.

Do you have any idea on how to come to an solution?

Thanks and all the best!

Comment: add you actual array in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$items = array(
  array( 'date' => '2014-09-10','type' => 'desktop', 'visits' => 10 ),
  array( 'date' => '2014-09-10', 'type' => 'tablet', 'conversion' => 5 ),
  array( 'date' => '2014-09-10', 'type' => 'desktop', 'visits' => 10 ),
  array( 'date' => '2014-09-10', 'type' => 'desktop', 'visits' => 10 ),
  array( 'date' => '2014-09-10','type' => 'tablet', 'conversion' => 10 ),
  array( 'date' => '2014-09-10', 'type' => 'desktop', 'visits' => 5 )
);

// sum of `visits`
$sum = array_sum(array_map(function($item){
                  return $item['visits'];
                },$items));

var_dump($sum);

// sum of `visits` by type `tablet`
$sum = array_sum(array_map(function($item){
                   return  ($item['type']=='tablet')?$item['visits']:null;
                },$items));

var_dump($sum);
```

Comment: Hi, this works great, thank you!

Just one additional question: if I add another dimension like 'source', how can I check for this as well?

So all Visits for Tablets from Source Google. Can I link these conditions?

Thanks again.

Comment: @user3182978 yes, change condition how u need.Example: `return  ( ($item['type']=='tablet') && ($item['source']=='Google') ) )?$item['visits']:null;

Comment: Thank you so much - works like a charm! I'll now try to get deeper into array_map to see what kind of magic is at work here ;)

Answer (score 1):

I will write it in pseudo PHP code, that's not my language but ideas are universal.

```
function sum($obj, $label){
    if( !is_array($obj) ){
        return 0;
    }
    $count = 0;
    foreach($obj as $key=>$val){
        if($key === $label){
            $count += $val;
        }
        if( is_array($val) ){
            $count += sum($val, $label);
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$visits = 0;
foreach($arr as $item)
   $visits += $item ['visits'];

echo $visits;
```